# Which event to look for User Mapping changes

Tags: sql-server-2014

We have been having issues where login's are having their user mapping changed unexpectedly and I am looking to have an alert fire off whenever that happens. Is there a way for me to capture that? I have been able to create a trigger for altering a login or changing their server roles, but not the user mapping itself.

**Edit** 
To be more clear, I am referring to database role memberships for users is what changing unexpectedly.

Comment: Do you mean users are not mapped to login anymore? Users are becoming orphan?

Comment: Edited the question, its the database role memberships changes I would like to catch

Comment: And thanks to your question, I was better to google what I was looking for and got an answer that worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for. I needed to check for the trigger event types ADD_ROLE_MEMBER and DROP_ROLE_MEMBER in my trigger at the ALL SERVER level.

I'll leave this up in case anyone else has a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can start a security audit and add audit action type `DATABASE_ROLE_MEMBER_CHANGE_GROUP`.

Ref:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions

https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/sqlserver/auditpolicy/auditactiongroups/database_role_member_change_group.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-add-member-to-db-role-event-class

This group tracks membership additions and removals on database roles.

If you enable this group in a server audit specification, that will track all new and remove members and database roles in all databases throughout the entire SQL Server instance. If you enable this group in a database audit specification, it will only track membership changes on database roles within that particular database.